# svn https proxy error handling externals definition

Tags: linux, svn, ssh, proxy, ssh-tunnel

The SVN server is on the internal work network.  Using a linux workstation, I only have access to the internal network through SSH to a server.

I have created a ssh tunnel on my workstation with:

> ssh -Nf -L443:svn.server:443 name@network_access.server

Using the following command gives me information on svn directory:

> svn info `https://localhost/directory/trunk`

Using:

> svn co `https://localhost/directory/trunk` test

Will pull several of the folders within trunk, and then halt before the following message appears.

> svn: warning: Error handling externals definition for
>   'test/trunk/folderx':
>
> svn: warning: OPTIONS of 'https://svn.server.com/directory/trunk': could
>   not connect to server (https://svn.server.com)

Any help greatly appreciated.